# Spring MVC. Servlet Application Context can't see AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean in Root Application Context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two application contexts in my SpringMVC application: appContext.xml (**Root Application Context**) and servletContext.xml (**Servlet Application Context**).

Beans in appContext.xml:

```
  <bean class="java.util.Random"/>
  <bean class="egor.spring.daos.impl.GamesDAOImpl"/>
  <bean class="egor.spring.services.impl.BaseServiceImpl"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>
```

Beans in servletContext.xml:

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <bean class="egor.spring.controllers.BaseController"/>
```

When I run my Tomcat server with these two contexts, it fails with 500 error.

**BUT** if I move `<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>` from appContext.xml to servletContext.xml - server works fine.

Why ServletApplicationContext cannot see BeanPostProcessor defined in RootApplicationContext ?

P.S. My BaseController contains fields with @Autowired annotation.

Comment: How/where are you loading the two xml contexts?

Comment: both are configired in web.xml, appContext.xml is loaded first (with ContextLoaderListener), then servletContext.xml (with DispatcherServlet) is loaded

Answer (score 0):

use `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`

Comment: Why? Can you offer an explanation?